# React event triggers visible page refresh when re rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out why any event triggers a visible page refresh when re-rendering. The following is the parent component :

```
export default function FullScreenDialog({purchaseList={"testtest":"900","heyzi":"90"}}) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [pieChartData,setPieChartData]=React.useState([])
  const [formset,setFormset]=React.useState([
    {
        id: uuidv4(),
        product:"",
        price: 0,
        quantity: 0,
        productSubtotal: 0,
    }
])

const singleForm= {
    id: uuidv4(),
    product:"",
    price: 0,
    quantity: 0,
    productSubtotal: 0,
}

const handleProduct = (e,id) => {   
    const newFormset=formset.map(item=>
        (item.id !== id? item : {
            ...item , product: e.target.value , price:purchaseList[e.target.value]
        })
    )
    setFormset(newFormset)
}

const handleQuantity = (e,id) => {
    const newFormset=formset.map((item)=>
    {
        if (item.id===id){
            const newItem={
                ...item, quantity: e.target.value
            }
            return newItem
        }
        return item
    })
    setFormset(newFormset)
}


const handleAdd=()=>{
    setFormset([...formset,singleForm])
}

const handleDelete=(id)=>{
    const newFormset=formset.filter(item=>
        item.id !==id
    )
    setFormset(newFormset)
}

//below is solely from this component, up is the state from children

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);  
    handlePieChartData()
  };



  const handlePieChartData=()=>{
    setPieChartData(
        [...pieChartData,{id:uuidv4(), data:formset }])
  }
  
   
  console.log(formset)
  console.log(pieChartData)
 

  return (
    <div>
      <ListOfPieChartsPresenter 
      open={open} 
      handleClickOpen={handleClickOpen} 
      handleClose={handleClose}  
      handleProduct={handleProduct}
      handleQuantity={handleQuantity}
      handleDelete={handleDelete}
      handleAdd={handleAdd}
      purchaseList={purchaseList}
      formset={formset}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the `ListOfPieChartsPresenter` component:

```
const ListOfPieChartsPresenter=({handleClickOpen,open,handleClose,handleProduct,handleQuantity,handleDelete,handleAdd,purchaseList,formset})=>{
  const classes = useStyles();

  const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
    return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
  });

  
    return (
        <div>
            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open full-screen dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog fullScreen open={open} onClose={handleClose} TransitionComponent={Transition}>
        <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" onClick={handleClose} aria-label="close">
              {/* <CloseIcon /> */}
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
              Sound
            </Typography>
            <Button autoFocus color="inherit" onClick={handleClose}>
              save
            </Button>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <form >
        <PieChartGroupForm
        handleProduct={handleProduct}
        handleQuantity={handleQuantity}
        handleDelete={handleDelete}
        handleAdd={handleAdd}
        purchaseList={purchaseList} 
        formset={formset}  />
        </form>
      </Dialog>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Lastly, this is the `PieChartGroupFormPresenter`:

```
const PieChartGroupFormPresenter=({handleProduct,handleQuantity,handleDelete,product,quantity,item,purchaseList,id})=>{
    return (
        <div>
            <FormControl>
            <Select onChange={(e)=>handleProduct(e,id)} value={product}>
                {Object.keys(purchaseList).map((item,index) =>
                    <MenuItem value={item} key={index}>{item}</MenuItem>
                )}
            </Select>
            <TextField onChange={(e)=>handleQuantity(e,id)} value={quantity} />
            <TextField value={item.price} disabled>{item.price}</TextField>
            <button onClick={()=>handleDelete(id)}>Delete</button>
            </FormControl>
            <br>

            </br>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have been reviewing this for approx an hour now and I still have no idea why this is happening. Could you please share your opinion? Thank you !

Comment: which event is causing re-render specifically?

Comment: @kevin any event ! that's what's so mind-blowing for me ...

Comment: try adding `event.preventdefault()` in form submit functions

Comment: @AmruthLS I have tried e.preventDefault() everywhere, yet this behaviour persists...

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that, with function components, *every* time the parent rerenders, the child will also rerender.  You can fix this via `React.memo`:

```js
const PieChartGroupFormPresenter = React.memo(({handleProduct,handleQuantity,handleDelete,product,quantity,item,purchaseList,id})=>{
  //...
});
```

The second issue is that every time you execute code like `const handleAdd=()=>{...}` you get a *different* function (closure). So each time `FullScreenDialog`'s state changes, it's going to change all the props passed to `ListOfPieChartsPresenter`.

You can use the [`useCallback` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to improve this: then the function/closure will change only when the specified dependencies change. For example:

```js
const handleAdd = React.useCallback(()=>{
    setFormset([...formset,singleForm])
}, [formset, singleForm]);
```

However, note that this callback function will still change whenever `formset` or `singleForm` change, so it will still cause a rerender when this state changes.

So hopefully it's at least clear why rerenders are happening, and why they are difficult to prevent.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with React transitions to figure out why they're triggering for each rerender.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply ! I tried to implement it , yet still doesnt work ...